# XGBoost leaf scores

Tags: python, xgboost

I am having a hard time understanding the leaf output of XGBoost. I am aware that probabilities can be computed using the sigmoid function, but how are the leaf scores actually computed and how do they make sense?

Can anyone help to explain? I read both the article and the docs. The following is a printet tree with leaf scores as well as the code to produce it.

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from xgboost import plot_tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=2000, n_features=4, n_informative=2, n_classes=2, n_clusters_per_class=1, random_state=42, weights=[0.1, 0.9])
model = XGBClassifier(objective="binary:logistic")
model.fit(X, y)

plot_tree(model, num_trees=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a long answer. But I provides you a working example of how to get the leaf scores manually and from there how to convert it into a probability scores that matches the xgboost `predict_proba` outputs.

This examples shows how to do it only for a binary classifier.

**Getting the leaf scores**

The `xgboost.core.Booster` has two methods that allows you to:

1. First, get the leaf indexes, using `xgboost.core.Booster.predict` with the parameter `pred_leaf` set to `True` that allows you to get the predicted leaf indices. Then, is just a matter of getting those indices scores.
2. To get the leaf scores, we resort to the method `xgboost.core.Booster.dump_model`, which dumps the structure of the tree ensemble as a plain text or json. The dump contains the leaf scores.

**Example**

First, train a xgboost model on the Iris Dataset.

```py
import os
import json

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn import datasets

# Load data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
y = (y == 1).astype(int)

# Fit a model
n_estimators = 10
max_depth = 10
model = xgb.XGBClassifier(
    n_estimators=n_estimators,
    max_depth=max_depth,
    min_child_weight=1)
model.fit(X, y)
booster = model.get_booster()
```

Then get leaf indices predictions.

```py
pred_leaf_index = booster.predict(
    xgb.DMatrix(X),
    pred_leaf=True
).reshape(X.shape[0], n_estimators)
```

To get the leaf scores we need to dump the model as a json file. The resulting dump contains the tree structure.

```py
# Dump the model and load the dump
model_json_path = '/tmp/model.json'
booster.dump_model(model_json_path, dump_format='json')
with open(model_json_path, 'r') as f:
    model_dict = json.loads(f.read())
```

Now, the following is perhaps the most complex part of this process. The following functions are aimed to get only the leaf scores by each three then for the entire ensamble:

```py
def get_tree_leaf_scores(tree):
    """Retrieve a single tree leaf scores.

    Parameters
    ----------
    tree : dict
        A dictionary representing a single xgboost decision tree 
        (one item of the dump generated by `booster.dump_model`).

    Returns
    -------
    leafs : list
        Each item of the list is the left and right final leafs of
        the final branch of a tree.
    """

    if 'leaf' in tree:
        return tree
    else:
        branch_0 = get_tree_leaf_scores(tree['children'][0])
        branch_1 = get_tree_leaf_scores(tree['children'][1])

        if not isinstance(branch_0, list):
            branch_0 = [branch_0]
        if not isinstance(branch_1, list):
            branch_1 = [branch_1]

        return branch_0 + branch_1

def get_trees_leaf_as_dataframe(model_dict):
    """Retrieve the tree ensemble leaf scores.

    Parameters
    ----------
    model_dict : dict
        The dictionary from loading the dump resulting from:
        `xgboost.core.Booster.dump_model`

    Returns
    -------
    trees_leaf_df : pandas.DataFrame
        Tree/node ids with their leaf score.
    """
    # Get tree nodes
    trees_leaf_df = []
    for tree_idx, tree in enumerate(model_dict):
        tree_leafs = get_tree_leaf_scores(tree)
        tree_leafs = pd.DataFrame(tree_leafs)
        tree_leafs['treeid'] = tree_idx

        trees_leaf_df.append(tree_leafs)

    trees_leaf_df = pd.concat(
        trees_leaf_df
    ).sort_values(['treeid', 'nodeid'])

    trees_leaf_df['id'] = \
        trees_leaf_df.apply(
            lambda x: '%s-%s' % (int(x['treeid']), int(x['nodeid'])), axis=1)

    trees_leaf_df = trees_leaf_df[
        ['treeid', 'nodeid', 'id', 'leaf']
    ].set_index('id')

    return trees_leaf_df
```

Here is how you get the leaf scores as a DataFrame:

```py
trees_leaf_df = get_trees_leaf_as_dataframe(model_dict)
trees_leaf_df.head()

Out[1]: 
   nodeid      leaf  treeid   id
0       1 -0.555556       0  0-1
4       4 -0.528000       0  0-4
3       6 -0.120000       0  0-6
1       7  0.150000       0  0-7
2       8  0.550000       0  0-8
```

At this point we are ready to get the model predicted leaf scores, with the help of the following function:

```py
def get_pred_leaf_scores(pred_leaf_index, trees_leaf_df):
    """
    Return
    ------
        The predicted leaf scores.
    """
    tree_ids = range(0, n_estimators)
    pred_leaf_scores = []
    for single_instance_pred_leafs in pred_leaf_index:
        tree_node_id_predictions = [
            '%s-%s' % (treeid, nodeid)
            for treeid, nodeid in zip(tree_ids, single_instance_pred_leafs)]

        single_instnace_pred_leaf_scores = trees_leaf_df.loc[
            tree_node_id_predictions]['leaf'].values

        pred_leaf_scores.append(single_instnace_pred_leaf_scores)

    pred_leaf_scores = pd.DataFrame(pred_leaf_scores)

    return pred_leaf_scores
```

```py
pred_leaf_scores = get_pred_leaf_scores(pred_leaf_index, trees_leaf_df)
pred_leaf_scores
Out[2]:
            0         1         2  ...         7         8         9
0   -0.555556 -0.434605 -0.373621  ... -0.248634 -0.231758 -0.215499
1   -0.555556 -0.434605 -0.373621  ... -0.248634 -0.231758 -0.215499
2   -0.555556 -0.434605 -0.373621  ... -0.248634 -0.231758 -0.215499
3   -0.555556 -0.434605 -0.373621  ... -0.248634 -0.231758 -0.215499
4   -0.555556 -0.434605 -0.373621  ... -0.248634 -0.231758 -0.215499
..        ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
145 -0.528000 -0.410725 -0.374272  ... -0.072375 -0.236201 -0.058543
146 -0.528000 -0.410725 -0.374272  ... -0.024406 -0.236201 -0.185685
147 -0.528000 -0.410725 -0.374272  ... -0.072375 -0.236201 -0.058543
148 -0.528000 -0.410725 -0.374272  ... -0.250879 -0.236201 -0.215589
149 -0.528000 -0.410725 -0.374272  ... -0.072375 -0.236201 -0.058543

[150 rows x 10 columns]
```

In the above DataFrame, rows are single predictions and the columns correspond to a single tree score output. In this example we have 10 columns, one for each tree in the ensamble. The sum of all tree outputs consists of the final model score (model score has to be transformed to a probability, more details in the following section).

**Getting probability scores**

Now comes the fun part.

Using the leaf scores you would use the sigmoid function to get the final probability scores. The sigmoid function only applies for the binary classifier scenario, for regression you would have to use a different formula.

The model scores are obtained as follow:

```py
def from_leafs_scores_to_proba(pred_leaf_scores):
    """
    """

    # Get logistic function logit.
    logit = pred_leaf_scores.sum(axis=1)

    # Compute the logistic function
    pos_class_probability = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-logit))

    return pos_class_probability

y_scores_from_leafs = from_leafs_scores_to_proba(pred_leaf_scores)

y_scores_from_leafs.values[:10]
Out[9]: 
array([0.03715579, 0.03715579, 0.03715579, 0.03715579, 0.03715579,
       0.03715579, 0.03715579, 0.03715579, 0.03715579, 0.03715579])
```

```py
y_scores = model.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]
y_scores[:10]
Out[10]: 
array([0.03715578, 0.03715578, 0.03715578, 0.03715578, 0.03715578,
       0.03715578, 0.03715578, 0.03715578, 0.03715578, 0.03715578],
      dtype=float32)
```